# Address is 3 bytes - need 4 bytes to overwrite RET

Tags: buffer-overflow

I have an issue. The address for a function that I need to overwrite the RET to (buffer overflow) is only 3 bytes. However, I need 4 bytes to overwrite the RET exactly. What do I do?

Comment: erm, set the highest byte to zero? I'm not sure if i understand your question correctly, though, one or two more sentences would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the architecture is 32-bit, every address must be 4 bytes so the function address you mentioned is not exception. but as high order 00 is not valuable (in math) it is not normally mentioned:

*0x0041a82f --> 0x41a82f*

You must overwrite your address in 4 bytes with former 00. but in many cases (especially string base overflow) it is a problem called "bad char", cause payload corruption. you have to fix this problem too.
Good Luck!

Comment: Yep I'm facing the problem you mentioned now :)